# Display image from a out side project directory using primefaces

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

i am new to primefaces and i am doing a project where i need to display multiple images from outside of a project directory. Lets think i have a folder called image in my C directory and there is multiple subfolder inside my image folder. I need to display all the images inside from a specific  subfolder  using p:gallery  of primefaces.

i have checked some example using  but i am not finding any output from it. please help me to solve it.

i have used following cooding

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.nio.file.Files;

    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    @WebServlet("/images/*")
    public class ImageServlet extends HttpServlet {



        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws            ServletException, IOException {


            try
            {
            String filename = request.getPathInfo().substring(1);
            System.out.println("path is"+filename);
            File file = new File("D:/images/", filename);
            response.setHeader("Content-Type", getServletContext().getMimeType(filename));
            response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(file.length()));
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");
            System.out.println("out put path"+file.toPath());
            Files.copy(file.toPath(), response.getOutputStream());
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("Exception is"+e.toString());
            }
        }

    }
```

and my page i have written

```
    <h:graphicImage value="/images/filename.ext" />
```

but i am getting following exception

path isfilename.ext

out put path

```
        D:\images\filename.ext
```

Exception is

```
      java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: D:\images\filename.ext
```

please give any suggetion

Comment: please help me to solve it

Comment: Mr.BalusC plz, help how to display the images. The above code is not working.

Answer (score 0):

[here](http://balusc.blogspot.it/2007/07/fileservlet.html) you can find a complete FileServlet class (yours is missing a couple of major things).

After you've modified FileServlet.java to fit for your purpose you should use

```
<p:graphicImage height="???" width="???"rendered="???" value="yout/path/#{image}" cache="????" />
```

in your page